# CSS: How to make header background transparent on Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, background, wordpress-theming

I want to have a background image on my site. It comes from the top of the page and is only behind the header. The problem is, my theme forces me to have a background color for the header so you can't see my background image at all. Here is a photo of what I want the site to look like:

[image: Here is a photo of what I want the site to look like]

And you can see what it actually looks like [here](http://www.gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/). I'm using the Brunch Pro theme on Wordpress.

Is there a way to make the header background transparent or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the end of the custom.css or style.css of your theme:

```
.brunch-pro .site-header{
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the CSS (which I presume you can in WP), look for where `.site-header` has it's CSS properties set. Remove the `background` and `background-color` properties.

You could also just add a new CSS property and apply it to the header. Something like:

```
header.site-header {
  background: none !important;
}
```

The `!important` will override already set properties...

Answer (score 0):

If `background-color` property is required, you could use `rgba` color and make it transparent. `background: rgba(0,0,0,0);` makes background-color black, but fully transparent, without opacity and other tricks. Like so:

```css
.black-but-transaprent {
  color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="black-but-transaprent">Test</div>
```